# Load different jQuery code by href?

Tags: jquery, parameter-passing, href

i have a menu like:

```
<a href="http://www.something.it/project/">TYPE 1</a>
<a href="http://www.something.it/project/">TYPE 2</a>
...
```

and i need to load this jQuery when the project page is loaded:

```
$('ul#filters li').each(function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('TYPE N')) {
    $(this).fadeOut('normal').addClass('hidden');
} else {
    $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
    }});
```

The href must pass the TYPE. If i click the link with "Type 1", after the project page loading i need to load:

```
$('ul#filters li').each(function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('Type 1')) {
    $(this).fadeOut('normal').addClass('hidden');
} else {
    $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
    }});
```

How can i do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Replace your following line:

```
if(!$(this).hasClass('TYPE 1')) {
```

for this one:

```
if( $(this).find('a').text() != 'TYPE 1') {
```

That should do what you want, comparing with the text content of the `<a>` element.